# MVC Site Compression not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-compression

I have done and checked the following.
1. made sure components are installed...[image]

2. Made sure everything is enabled for the server in IIS
   [image]
3. Made sure the site has modules enabled 
   [image]
4. Enabled the settings in web.config

   ```
   <system.webServer>
     <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
   </system.webServer>
   ```

My site here http://tinyurl.com/lv44hl4 according to few sites when i enter my url in it says not compressed, for example

http://tinyurl.com/nzfv9z4 (GZIP TEST SITE WITH MY URL)

Am i missing something? (using IIS8, mvc5 and .net 4.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-Shift-I will open developer tools in Google Chrome. According to that your content is compressed via gzip.

[image: GZIPED]

Comment: google pagespeed says my javascript files are not compressed even though I have used bundling and all the above steps

Comment: Yep thats a bit of a classic with IIS. Check your httpCompression config section and make sure you have an entry for application/javascript as often IIS will just have application/x-javascript and depending on how your server is set up text/* wont pick it up either as this is an old invalid way of referencing script files. So you'll need an <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" /> entry in dynamic types not just a <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />

Comment: my server has one for .js application/javascript but does not have one for application/x-javascript so do i need to add one? for x version?

Comment: Ok I've looked at your site again via Chome Dev Tools and your scripts are being sent down as text/javascript which is a bit outdated but they are being gzipped (main.js, places.js, etc). The only thing not being gzipped is your bundles. If you absolutely must zip these then try https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/ but they have been javascript compressed already so you might just be over optimising. Remember compression is not free. It increases server load, sometimes significantly. i.e. reduce data transfer, eat CPU. On something like Azure, data transfer could be cheaper than CPU.